# Prolog | Unification

Tags: prolog, unification

I have the follow terms :

```
3 
p(X)

3
p(x, X)

3
p(x,_)
```

My question is regarding unification.
For example: would "3" unify with "p(X)" [Some p, doesn't matter atm]

Now, my gut feeling is this :
First term will unify (X = 3)
Second term will unify ( X = 3 )
Third term I'm not sure about, I think that it would too... (As _ = 3)

Anyone that can shed some light on this one for me ? 
Thanks

Comment: p(X) is a purely syntactic term. 3 is a constant/integer. p(X) = 3 fails, regardless of X.

Comment: OK, thanks,but isn't because prolog being backtracking based X is unified before p(X) ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with backtracking.  To understand unification, it suffices to look at goals like `p(X) = 3` which fails or `p(X) = p(3)`  which succeeds with `X = 3`.

Comment: So if I get you right, all three fail?

Comment: yes ...................................

Comment: Alright thank you, please write this as answer so I can vote